# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION occurs on my Swift code, which doesn't have any syntactical issue

Tags: ios, swift

I've been playing around with Swift code to get accustomed to it, but when I run the code snippet in `main.swift` file (not a playground), the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` was shown on the screen.

The error points to the following line:

```
// loop
let scores:Int[] = [52, 53, 12, 53]
for score in scores {
    println("The score is \(score)")
} // <- the error points to this line
```

However, I don't know why the code above is subject to the error. Is there anything wrong with the snippet above?

Even if I rewrite the above code to the following (add the explicit type to the variable within loop):

```
// loop
let scores:Int[] = [52, 53, 12, 53]
for score:Int in scores {
    println("The score is \(score)")
}
```

, the error is still there.

So how can I cope with the issue here? I use Xcode 6 beta on OS X Yosemite dev preview.

Comment: works in REPL. are you sure this is the code cause the problem? try delete them and run again

Comment: I deleted those lines but the same error still happens on the different line.

Comment: What does the callstack look like when the program stops?

Comment: To make it clear, the actual code consists of 250 lines, but the same error continues to occur on the different line whenever I delete the part that is causing the error.

Comment: FYI, EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION means that there was an Assertion that failed in the code. Likely this is an assertion within the swift standard library, for safety reasons.

Comment: Is there any way to detect where the assertion is called in my code?

Comment: Yes, by looking at the call stack in your debugger when the error is thrown (and the program is stopped)

Comment: keep deleting code until no more error. then add code back until error appear again.

Comment: Ah, OK. I found the JSON parse error which is on line 240. But then why does it point to the line 40 (which I write the code snippet above), despite the error happens on line 240? It makes it difficult to track the part that caused the error in the first place...

Comment: My guess is a bug in Xcode or the swift compiler. It is beta software after all

Comment: Thank you for the help though. My problem is resolved. Could you post it as an answer? I want to close the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION means that there was an Assertion that failed in the code. Likely this is an assertion within the swift standard library, for safety reasons.

You should be able to look at the call stack when the program stops from the runtime error to investigate where the problem is and what is causing it.

Comment: uhah! what a way of reporting a failed assertion